# Why is process.env.DATABASE undefined on macOS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I have a MERN application that runs fine on a Windows machine, but when trying to deploy it to a colleague's macOS machine we're getting the below error. Console logging `process.env.DATABASE` reveals it is `undefined` on the macOS machine. We tried setting the variable by running `export NODE_ENV=development` in the console but still get the same error.

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

const db = require('./database');
const router = require('./routes');

const app = express();

require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  key: process.env.KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongoUrl: process.env.DATABASE })
}));

app.use('/api', router);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);

const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express running on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

variables.env

```
NODE_ENV=development
DATABASE=database path
```

error in console:

```
> server@1.0.0 start
> node ./index.js
Assertion failed: You must provide either mongoUrl|clientPromise|client in options
/Users/user/Documents/ATT-main/server/node_modules/connect-mongo/build/main/lib/MongoStore.js:119
            throw new Error('Cannot init client. Please provide correct options');
            ^
Error: Cannot init client. Please provide correct options
    at new MongoStore (/Users/user/Documents/ATT-main/server/node_modules/connect-mongo/build/main/lib/MongoStore.js:119:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/ATT-main/server/index.js:32:10)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you restart the server after making the changes in the `.env` file?

Comment: @dsomel21 just restarted the mac and get the same result.

Comment: ```
const path = require('path')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const envFile = `${path.join(__dirname, 'variables.env')}`
dotenv.config({ path: `${envFile}` })
```

Comment: Sometimes I have issues with the path to files. Try using the path module and maybe we'll get lucky

Comment: @cWerning same error after replacing `require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });` with `const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const envFile = `${path.join(__dirname, 'variables.env')} `
dotenv.config({ path: envFile })`

Comment: If the path is wrong you will not get an error. The vaiables.env file is definitely in the same directory as you index.js file?

Comment: On UNIX like operating systems environment variables are not global. Changing an env var in a shell process will not affect any other running process. It will only affect processes that are subsequently spawned by that shell. I have no idea what a "MERN application" is but I will bet you are starting it via a mechanism such as a crontab or MacOS launchd context which does not export the env var. Alternatively, given your confusing question you might be using the wrong env var name: `NODE_ENV` versus `DATABASE`.